# Number guessing game - how to fix it?

Tags: java, if-statement, random

How do I make this so once the user inputs a number and presses enter(or something) it runs the `if` `else` statements?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("please guess the number between 1 and 100.");

    boolean run = true;
    int y = 0;

    Random ran = new Random();
    int x = ran.nextInt(99);

    while (run == true) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter(" ");
        // System.out.println(scan.nextInt());

        y = scan.nextInt();

        /*
         * if(y > 0){ run = false; } else{ run = true; }
         */
        if (y > x) {
            System.out.println("Lower...");
        } else if (y < x) {
            System.out.println("Higher...");
        } else if (y == x) {
            System.out.println("Correct!");
            try {
                Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();

                System.exit(0);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run the if-else statements"? Are you talking about the ones that are commented out?

Comment: You should use `Thread.sleep(...)` instead of `Thread.currentThread().sleep(...)` because it's a static method; your code might tempt you to do `someOtherThread.sleep(...)` which does not sleep `someOtherThread`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works as is.  It is just that your input needs to be delimited by spaces.

If you input a single number and hit enter, there will be no space, and as you have set your `Scanner` up to be delimited by spaces, it wont find anything.  On the other hand, if you input:

```
3 9
```

(`3` [space] `9`), your Scanner will pick up the 3.  What you probably want is this:

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\n");
```

so that your `Scanner` will read a number after you hit enter.  No matter which way you do this, you will want to put some error handling around the `Scanner` to handle `InputMismatchException`s.

Comment: thanks for the answer! I forget that \n is <enter> so i just pressed enter in the delimiter and it only got the first digit so then i tried to get the entire # through much more complicated methods! thanks for the answer which completely solved my problems!

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not very clear, the following changes seem logical, given the structure of your code:

```
           else if (y == x) {
                   System.out.println("Correct!");
                   run = false;
           }
```

and of course just `if(run)` (a matter of good style)

Answer (score 0):

Your code didn't actually generate numbers between 1 and 100 inclusive (rather, between 0 and 98 inclusive). Fixing this bug and adding some error checking, your code becomes:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HiLo {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int guess = 0, number = new Random().nextInt(100) + 1;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please guess the number between 1 and 100.");

    while (guess != number) {
      try {
        if ((guess = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine())) != number) {
          System.out.println(guess < number ? "Higher..." : "Lower...");
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("Correct!");
        }
      }   
      catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid number!");
      }   
      catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        break; // EOF
      }   
    }   

    try {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }   
  }
}
```